# Continuous Entropy and Maximum Entropy Solution

Tags: self-study, maximum-entropy

This is a problem that I have been working on and the mathematics of it have me fairly stumped.

I am given the continuous entropy for a density $p(x)$.  It is $H(X)=-\int_{0}^{\infty}p(x)\text{log}\: p(x)dx$.  Also given that $E(X)=\mu$.

I am directed to find an upper bound of $H(X)$ as a function of $\mu$.  I also need to show that the maximum entropy solution is the exponential density.

I am given the functional that I need to optimize.  It is as follows:

$$J[p(x)]=-\int_{0}^{\infty}p(x)\text{log}p(x)dx +\lambda_1\left [  \int_{0}^{\infty}p(x)dx-1\right ]+\lambda_2\left [  \int_{0}^{\infty}xp(x)dx-\mu\right ]$$

Now, I am given that I need to solve the equation $\frac{\partial J}{\partial p}=0$, where the delta is functional derivative.  I am taking this to mean that I need to take the derivative with respect to $p$ and set it to zero.

I should end up with an equation that is a function of $p(x)$ and of $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$.

How do I go about actually taking that partial derivative?  Once I have that derivative function, how do I use it to find the upper bound?

I am having trouble locating information regarding these problems in other locations on the internet.  I am not looking for an exact solution, but rather the method I need to use to approach this problem.

Thank you for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply a [functional derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_derivative) in this case, use the Euler-Lagrange formula:
Given
$$\mathcal{F}[f] = \int_a^b G(f(x), f'(x)) dx$$
$$\frac{\delta \mathcal{F}}{\delta f} = \frac{\partial G}{\partial f(x)} - \frac{d}{dx}\frac{\partial G}{\partial f'(x)}$$

Since the functional in your case does not depend on the derivative of $f$, the expression becomes already much easier
$$\frac{\delta \mathcal{F}}{\delta f} = \frac{\partial G}{\partial f(x)}$$
and you can treat it almost like a 'normal' derivative with respect to a variable.

All that's left to do is to solve your [constrained optimization problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier).

I recommend Bishop's 'Pattern Recognition in Machine Learning' Ch. 1.6 about Information Theory and Appendix D about Calculus of Variations, those are great resources to learn about this topic.

Comment: Tinu, thank you very much for the answer!  I suppose I am still having trouble seeing how to treat it like a normal derivative.  Because the p(x) is under an integral with respect to x, how do I take a derivative of it with respect to p(x).  That is the problem I am having.  Could you expand on that a little bit?

Comment: Figure out how your function $G(p(x))$ **inside** the integral looks like, try to see what is constant (you can ignore constant terms when maximizing). Then apply Euler-Lagrange and treat $p(x)$ like a variable.

Comment: Tinu, I see now with that formula.  The integral becomes non-important in this case, as the formula has already been worked out by people much more intelligent than I am.  I do not full understand why, but perhaps that will come later.  I will go from there when I am home from work.  Thank you very much for your help with this!